# Transfer two array content values of same count into key value pair

Tags: json, jq, key-value

I have a question.
Let's assume I had a json doc like this:

```
{
  "counts": [
    17,
    1014,
    22,
    9,
    11
  ],
  "values": [
    "5",
    "10",
    "15",
    "20",
    "25"
  ]
}
```

and I wanted to get a result like this:

```
{
    "5":17,
    "10":1014,
    "15":22,
    "20":9,
    "25":11
}
```

basically the array elements assigned as key value pairs one after the other. How can I achieve that?

I tried jq `with_entries(.values = .counts)` and `with_entries(.values[] = .counts[])` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `transpose` with `reduce`:

```
[ .counts, .values ] | transpose | reduce .[] as $t ({}; .[$t[1]] = $t[0])
```

Output:

```json
{
  "5": 17,
  "10": 1014,
  "15": 22,
  "20": 9,
  "25": 11
}
```

##### [Online Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PCKTPp9C5_V)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two `transpose`-free solutions:

```bash
[(.counts | keys[]) as $i | {(.values[$i]): .counts[$i]}] | add
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BvYM4HL07HA)

```bash
. as {$values} | .counts | with_entries(.key |= $values[.])
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M_dZutsBnJR)

Output:

```json
{
  "5": 17,
  "10": 1014,
  "15": 22,
  "20": 9,
  "25": 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @pmf's answer here is a slight improvement:

```
. as $in
| reduce (.values|keys[]) as $i (
    {};
    .[$in.values[$i]] = $in.counts[$i]
)
```

It avoids some intermediate objects either hidden in `with_entries` or plain
visible before the `add` and goes directly to `reduce` which is also used both by `with_entries` and `add`.